# Make Voice Call and Video Call in android

Tags: android

I want to create an app used to make Voice Call and Video Call, but I don't know if this service will be free? and I am from Egypt
Any lesson will be appreciated,
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use GOOGLE. There are plenty of examples, blogs and other library to SUPPORT you !!!

Comment: does google support my country?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47096054/android-how-to-integrate-video-calling-in-my-android-application/47117314#47117314

Answer (score 2):

you should use QuickBlox this is good one for audio and Video.

http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try oovoo sdk? All you need to customize it according to your requirements.

https://developers.oovoo.com/

Also there is a tutorial to use this sdk.

https://developers.oovoo.com/docs

Comment: Is it full free ? or for number of calls

Comment: full free :) if you found this fullfilling ur requirements plz accept the answer.

Comment: Both links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution, A Complete SDK's & API for voice & video call. Visit this [link](https://blog.contus.com/video-call-integration/)